# Can't change desktop wallpaper after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10. All things working fine but I can't change my desktop wallpaper. Whenever I try to change,it changes to solid color only. I'm using the GNOME desktop, not Unity.

Please help me out

Comment: You have all done with edited my question, thanks for that but now where is the answer ???

Comment: there are the answers ^

Answer (score 11):

From Desktop shows a white or black background instead of wallpapers:

Open terminal by pressing Crl+Alt+t and use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem because I mostly use xfce4 and  had set nautilus to not control the desktop (`nautilus --no-desktop`). Switching over to Unity, I had no wallpaper.

Try opening a terminal and type

```
nautilus --force-desktop &
```

(thats 2 dashes before force and one after)

If you get your wallpaper back it means nautilus isn't controlling the desktop at the moment.

I used to be able to use Ubuntu Tweak to set that switch but it isn't showing up in mine (version 0.8.6).

You could also try downloading `gnome-tweak-tool` and set the switch in it. This is my first time answering and the formatting  is too hard to figure out at 2:24 am so I hope you can make sense of this :)